# TCP dump filter requests containing certain values

Tags: regex, grep, tcpdump

My current tcpdump operation does log all requests on http port on certain interface:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -C 100 -W 100 -w traffic port http
```

problem is, at this point tcpdump is collecting all request (even with sensible information from my login page). At this point I have to egrep through my tcpdump file, and egrep those file to put them out. Is there any way to integrate searching for certain text values in my request, and if they're present - to not log this request to file?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `tshark`(the CLI created by wireshark)  instead of `tcpdump`, it allows you to  run `lua` scripts.

It's a rather advanced topic, but worth investigating you can take a look at:

https://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua/Examples

IMHO you should not solve this problem with regex, you are better of blurring sensitive information(print **** ) instead of removing those completely.

Also chances are that sensitive information are being posted to an endpoint like `/login` and because Tshark parses HTTP protocol in your lua script you could write decisions based on path field.

Comment: Or is there any way to just pass data from tcpdump not to file, but to next pipeline with grep behind it?

Comment: It depends on what output you want, if do that you will end up with a text file, which may be ok for your use case but ideally you have a pcap file which you could analyze further. But yes, you can output the payload to STDOUT and use grep. `tcpdump -As 1024`  will send first 1024 bytes to STDOUT

Comment: will not pipelining tcpdump, and then saving it to a file (after grepping) would save the data in the same format as tcpdump to file itself?

Comment: Nope, you will end up with a text file unfortunately.